# What counts as an operator and operand in PHP when calculating Halstead complexity?

Tags: php, operators, metrics, operands

I have this code that I want to use for calculating the Halstead complexity:

```
<?php
$words = explode("\n", file_get_contents('http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/unixdict.txt'));
foreach ($words as $word) {
    $chars = str_split($word);
    sort($chars);
    $anagram[implode($chars)][] = $word;
}

$best = max(array_map('count', $anagram));
foreach ($anagram as $ana)
    if (count($ana) == $best)
        print_r($ana);
?>
```

I understand the principles of how it is done (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halstead_complexity_measures), but what I don't understand and also couldn't find out after thoroughly searching, is: **What exactly counts as an operator, and what counts as an operand?** There doesn't seem to be a agreed upon definition.

Here's an easier example (http://www.win.tue.nl/~aserebre/2IS55/2009-2010/9.pdf) which I can follow, but can't apply in the example above.

Comment: not a great measure for php

Answer (score 1):

As I understand this metric, operators are all operators (`==`, `+`, `++`, and so on) and keywords (`for`, `if`, `break`, `function`) of the language you are using.
Operands will be every identifier, i.e. function names (self writtend functions and also built in functions), variable names and constants.

To your example:
**Operators**: `foreach` (`as` is obligatory, so I dont count it), `[]` (this is like `+=`, just with appanding instead of adding sth.), `if`, `==`
**Operands**: `$words`, `explode`, `$word`, `str_split`, `$chars`, `sort`, `$anagram`, `implode`, `$best`, `max`, `array_map`, `$ana`, `cound`, `print_r`

*Notice*: This code metric seems not to be used for PHP very often, so I also have not found any reference or example for this metric used on PHP code.

Comment: According to wikipedia, they count even the opening `(` for the `printf(`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halstead_complexity_measures. Unless I'm counting wrong?

Comment: @AlexKwitny Yes, they count every pair of parenthesis as an operator.

Comment: I read that "( as is obligatory, so I don't count it".  I see you highlighted `as`. I thought you were talking about the `(`. Perhaps you have an opinion on my Halstead question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32364095/how-to-count-operators-and-operands-for-halstead-complexity-measures?noredirect=1#comment52602473_32364095